# Multi Line Memo in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am confused to get a particular word started line in Memo in Delphi 7

I have something like this

```
Memo1.lines.text:= *Some execution process*;
```

**and the result in Memo1 is**

```
I have something to do 
I have never gone there 
We are playing Tenis
You are so sweet

I am going there
```

Now How can I get only the line started with **We** instead of whole bunch of lines

like in the above Memo lines

**We are playing Tenis**

Comment: does your memo wrap too long (too wide) lines? or are those lines shorter than its width ?

Comment: Why are you using a visual control for what appears to be text searching?

Comment: Is your question about how to scroll down to a given line, so the line is on top of the visible range?

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  As it stands, it is badly formed.

Answer (score 3):

If you know you always want a specific line (like the third in your sample), access it directly. `Lines`, like `TStringList`, is zero-based, so subtract one:

```
YourLine := Memo1.Lines[2];
```

If you only have part of the text at the beginning of the line, you can iterate through each line and use `StrUtils.StartsText`:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  FoundAt: Integer;
begin
  FoundAt := -1;
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if StrUtils.StartsText('We', Memo1.Lines[i]) then
      FoundAt := i;
  end;
  if FoundAt <> -1 then
    YourText := Memo1.Lines[FoundAt];
end;
```

In Delphi 7, use `AnsiStartsText` instead (also found in the `StrUtils` unit).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but I get the similar result as usual by your code implementation . .. I have not to achieve it from line number but a line starts with specific word.. the bunch of lines are in Memo1 after some code execution .. and there comes with bunch of lines in memo .. instead of displaying whole bunch of lines result .. I need to display a single line with specific word .. say **We**

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know what that means. You just commented with the same code I posted already.

Comment: IndexOf must match the full string, no?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Not in TStringList. Maybe in TMemo.Lines - I'll have to check.

Comment: @ken check http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TStrings.IndexOf

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Yep, TMemo.Lines requires a full string to match. Correcting.

Comment: OK, let me twist my question to achieve what I actually want .. say **Memo1** have **10 lines** and in those ten lines there is one line starts with word **What** ..Now How can get the particular lines in Memo2 .. Not only **What** but a **whole Line starts with** what .. as I know there is single line in Memo1 starts with **What**

Comment: That's the last block of code I gave you. Replace `'We'` with `'What'` in the call to `StrUtils.StartsWith`.

Comment: @stiphen:  If you are using Delphi 7, how did you manage to compile Ken's coe.  IIRC, there was no StartsText in D7, but there was an AnsiStartsText.

Comment: I get the error _undeclared identifier_ for **StartsText** , and I used **StrUtils** in _uses_

Comment: @stiphen, that's what you would get.  Use AnsiStartsText instead.  Btw, it is *really* unhelpful to say "but I get the similar result as usual by your code implementation" - which implies that you have compiled and run the code, when you couldn't have compiled it in the first place!

Comment: Sorry. Missed that you were using D7. See my edit, final paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Uses `StrUtils`

```
Function sExtractBetweenTagsB(Const s, LastTag, FirstTag: string): string;
var
  pLast,pFirst,pNextFirst : Integer;
begin
  pFirst := Pos(FirstTag,s);
  pLast := Pos(LastTag,s);
  while (pLast > 0) and (pFirst > 0) do begin
    if (pFirst > pLast) then // Find next LastTag
      pLast := PosEx(LastTag,s,pLast+Length(LastTag))
    else
    begin
      pNextFirst := PosEx(FirstTag,s,pFirst+Length(FirstTag));
      if (pNextFirst = 0) or (pNextFirst > pLast) then begin
        Result := Trim(Copy(s,pFirst,pLast-pFirst+Length(LastTag)));
        Exit;
      end
      else
        pFirst := pNextFirst;
    end;
  end;
  Result := '';
end;
```

Usage like this

```
procedure TForm24.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(sExtractBetweenTagsB(Memo1.Text,sLineBreak,'We'));
  //or
  ShowMessage(sExtractBetweenTagsB(Memo1.Text,'Tenis','We'));
end;
```

Output: `We are playing Tenis`

Answer (score 0):

```
j := FirstLineStarting( Memo1.Lines, 'we' );
if j >= 0 then 
   ShowMessage( Memo1.Lines[j] ); 


.....


function FirstLineStarting( const Text: TStrings; const Pattern: string; const WithCase: Boolean = false): integer;
var i: integer;
    check: function (const ASubText, AText: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := -1; // not found

  if WithCase
     then check := StartsStr
     else check := StartsText;

  for i := 0 to Text.Count - 1 do
     if check( Pattern, Text[i] ) then begin
        Result := i;
        break;
     end; 
end;
```

Comment: None of the Answer helped .. Am I failed to explain my question ?

Comment: @stiphen Both seem to be addressing your question as explained. Could it be that you don't want those lines to appear in the memo in the first place?

Comment: well, for starters you are to describe what do you mean by "not helped" - we cannot know what behavior do you see if you would not describe it http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise
 //// 
also you did not answered my comment to your question above.
we do not even know whether your memo has one line wrapped or many lines non-wrapped or maybe many lines some of them wrapped - so we only try to guess what data you really have